# Актуальность вендорных префиксов

Tags: css

На дворе 2к17 год, CSS3 скоро отпразднует первый юбилей, браузеры претерпели кучу обновлений, поэтому встаёт вопрос: а нужно ли до сих пор использовать вендорные префиксы? И если нужно, то для каких свойств?

Comment: http://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/ и все.

Comment: Капитан Очевидность замечает, что вендорные префиксы нужны там, где вы собираетесь поддерживать те версии браузеров, которые не поддерживают нужные вам свойства без вендорных префиксов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Процитирую фрагмент из книги Леа Веру "Секреты CSS. Идеальные решения ежедневных задач".

> #### Песнь льда, пламени и браузерных префиксов
>
> Разработка стандартов всегда по своей природе парадоксальна: группы по
>   подготовке стандартов нуждаются в информации от разработчиков, для
>   того чтобы создавать спецификации, регулирующие реальные потребности
>   разработчиков. Но разработчики, в целом, не слишком заинтересованы в
>   том, чтобы тестировать вещи, которые они не могут применять в своей
>   работе. Когда экспериментальные технологии начинают широко
>   использоваться в производстве, у рабочей группы не остается иного
>   выхода, кроме как придерживаться ранней, экспериментальной версии
>   технологии, так как ее изменение способно поломать уже существующие
>   веб-сайты. Очевидно, это полностью сводит на нет преимущества, которые
>   способно принести тестирование ранних версий стандартов реальными
>   разработчиками.
>
> За прошедшие годы было предложено множество вариантов выхода из этой
>   непростой ситуации, но все они далеки от идеала. Повсеместно
>   презираемые браузерные префиксы — один из них. Идея заключалась в том,
>   что для каждого браузера могут быть реализованы экспериментальные (или
>   даже патентованные) возможности, к названиям которых необходимо
>   добавлять специальный префикс. Наиболее распространенные префиксы —
>   это `-moz-` для Firefox, `-ms-` для IE, `-o-` для Opera и `-webkit-`
>   для Safari и Chrome. Разработчикам предлагалось свободно
>   экспериментировать с этими специальными возможностями и делиться
>   своими впечатлениями с рабочей группой. Рабочая группа, в свою
>   очередь, должна была учитывать обратную связь от разработчиков при
>   подготовке спецификаций, постепенно доводя соответствующую
>   функциональность до совершенства. Так как у финальной,
>   стандартизированной версии должно было быть другое название (без
>   префикса), ее добавление не должно было порождать коллизии в
>   продуктах, использующих уже существующие, обремененные префиксом
>   эквиваленты.
>
> Звучит отлично, не так ли? Но, как вы уже, вероятно, знаете,
>   реальность оказалась совершенно непохожей на то, что планировалось
>   воплотить. Когда разработчики осознали, что эти экспериментальные
>   зависимые от браузера свойства позволяют с легкостью создавать
>   эффекты, реализация которых ранее требовала огромных усилий и
>   запутанных обходных путей, они принялись использовать их где только
>   можно. Свойства с браузерными префиксами быстро превратились в модную
>   тенденцию в мире CSS. Выпускались учебники, публиковались ответы на
>   сайте StackOverflow, и скоро практически каждый уважающий себя
>   CSS-разработчик обвешивал ими свои сайты с ног до головы.
>
> В конце концов разработчики осознали, что если использовать только
>   существующие браузерные префиксы, то к уже имеющемуся коду необходимо
>   возвращаться и добавлять новые объявления каждый раз, когда в новом
>   браузере появляется поддержка их любимой классной возможности CSS. Не
>   говоря уж о том, что все префиксы, необходимые для той или иной
>   возможности, вообще довольно сложно держать в памяти. Решение? Конечно
>   же, всегда использовать все возможные браузерные префиксы, в конце
>   заодно добавляя версию без префикса, для того чтобы гарантировать
>   правильную обработку кода в будущем. В результате код стал выглядеть
>   примерно так:
>
> ```
> -moz-border-radius: 10px;
>  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
>  -o-border-radius: 10px;
>  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
>  border-radius: 10px;
> ```
>
> Среди этих объявлений два избыточны: `-ms-border-radius` и
>   `-o-border-radius` никогда ни в каком браузере не существовали, так
>   как в IE и Opera с самого начала было реализовано свойство
>   `border-radius` безо всякого префикса. Очевидно, что повторять каждое
>   объявление до пяти раз невероятно утомительно, а результирующий код не
>   приспособлен для нормальной поддержки. Появление инструментов, которые
>   автоматизировали бы это, было исключительно вопросом времени:
>
> - на таких веб-сайтах, как **CSS3, Please!** (http://css3please.com)
>     и pleeease (http:// pleeease.io/playground.html), вы можете вставить
>     CSS-код без префиксов и получить обратно CSS со всеми необходимыми
>     префиксами. Подобные приложения стали одними из первых реализаций
>     автоматического добавления браузерных префиксов, но быстро растеряли
>     свою популярность, так как по сравнению с другими решениями довольно
>     неудобны в использовании;
> - Autoprefixer (http://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) использует базу
>     данных из **Can I Use…** (http://caniuse.com) для определения, какие
>     префиксы необходимо добавить к коду без браузерных префиксов, и
>     компилирует его локально, как препроцессор;
> - моя собственная утилита **-prefix-free**
>     (http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree) выполняет тестирование
>     возможностей в браузере, определяя, какие префиксы требуются. Ее
>     преимущество в том, что она крайне редко требует обновления, так как
>     получает всю необходимую информацию, включая список свойств, из
>     окружения браузера;
> - такие препроцессоры, как **LESS** (http://lesscss.org) и **Sass**
>     (http://sass-lang.com), не предлагают стандартной функциональности
>     добавления префиксов, но многие разработчики создают собственные
>     подборки для возможностей, с которыми они чаще всего используют
>     браузерные префиксы, и в обращении можно найти несколько подобных
>     библиотек.
>
> Поскольку разработчики использовали версии без префиксов в качестве
>   гарантии работоспособности своего кода в будущем, изменять их стало
>   невозможно. По сути, мы зашли в тупик с полусырыми ранними
>   спецификациями, допускающими лишь незначительные изменения. Совсем
>   скоро все пришли к осознанию, что **браузерные префиксы были эпическим
>   провалом**.
>
> Сегодня браузерные префиксы применяются для новых экспериментальных
>   реализаций очень редко. Вместо этого экспериментальные возможности
>   включаются с помощью конфигурационных флагов, что предотвращает
>   использование их разработчиками в производственном окружении, — ведь
>   вы не можете заставлять пользователей менять локальные настройки для
>   того, чтобы веб-сайт на их машинах отображался правильно. Разумеется,
>   следствием этого стало то, что теперь гораздо меньше разработчиков
>   тестируют экспериментальные возможности, но мы все же получаем
>   достаточно обратной связи — и, возможно, более высококачественной
>   обратной связи, — не испытывая при этом сложностей, порождаемых
>   браузерными префиксами. Однако пройдет еще немало времени, прежде чем
>   мы полностью избавимся от неприятных последствий существования
>   браузерных префиксов.

#### Личное мнение:

Не добавляйте бреузерные префиксы без веской на то причины. Просто погуглите новое для вас свойство на предмет поддержки браузеров. Слишком часто вижу добавление префиксов, которые нужны были в очень старых браузерах, которые вряд ли кто-то поддерживает (к примеру, которые нужны были в самых первых версиях Firefox или Chrome) на том же StackOverflow.

Comment: хороший перевод и нужная информация к размышлению